# Why isn't it possible to dynamically create a variable via self-invoking function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to imitate some sort of constructor like in other programming languages.
If I do it like this it doesn't work. :/ Sorry for being dumb! :/
Thanks for the help!!

```
  function foo(){

      this.makeVar = function(){this.newVar = 'hello world'}(); 

  }

 var test = new foo();
 alert(test.newVar);
```

Comment: @BoltClock — no, there is no `new` keyword, so it refers to `window` not the object being instantiated (since there is no such object).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are calling the (anonymous) function directly, and not as a method on an object. So `this` is `window`.

Copy the value of `this` in the outside function to a variable that is still available on the inside function.

```
function foo(){
  var self = this;
  this.makeVar = function(){
    self.newVar = 'hello world';
  }(); 
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be nicer to just do `function(){...}.call(this);` rather than making a new reference.

Comment: Wow thank you sir!!! I didn't realize that! At first I thought 'this' was already valid since I've instantiated foo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't apologise for "being dumb". Asking questions is actually smart (usually).

The function `foo()` already is a constructor, so there's no need for an internal constructor's constructor.

Comment: I'm really not used to asking questions, I'm actually new to this lol. Many thanks!!